# How P2P applications find other nodes?

Tags: networking, distributed, p2p

I was wondering how in a decentralized P2P network each node can find other nodes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this article: http://cs.berry.edu/~nhamid/p2p/

But in general you've a server with a list a known peers to advertise.

Also, if you're looking for an implementation less "peer server" dependent, take a look here: [TCP P2P without server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392016/tcp-p2p-without-server).

Comment: So this means that if someone shutdown Tor's servers, all the network won't work?

Comment: In short, yes. https://www.torproject.org/about/overview#thesolution take a look. But most of the clients are already to each other and the network will keep running. New clients will have to wait.

Comment: @TCB13 I'm doing something similar and was wondering if I was nuts for deriving the same solution (well, slightly different, long running nodes gradually try to find peers fewer hops away). Now I feel slightly less silly for making nodes that don't yet have a cache of previous working peers wait. Hole-punching is another annoyance, of course.